# Converting HH:MM:SS column in dataframe to minutes column

Tags: r

**New to R**
I am working with a dataframe and it has a column which is of type datetime and is in the format HH:MM:SS. I tried few functions that I got from different sources but nothing worked.
A column named ride length is in hh:mm:ss format and I want to create a new column in the same dataframe which stores the ride_length values in minutes in a new column.

```
time2minutes <- function(x){
  c(as.matrix(read.table(text = df$ride_length, sep = ":"))%*%c(60,1,1/60))
}

transform(df, ride_length_minutes = time2minutes(df$ride_length))
```

Here df is the parent dataframe, ride_length is the column in df where the values are stored in HH:MM:SS format

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include a sample from your dataset like suggested in [r] tag description,  e.g. output of `dput(head(df_["ride_length"]))`  in your case.  From the code you provided, we could assume "hh:mm:ss" strings, but in your question you mention datetime type, which could mean POSIXct. And then there's again a format without a date part. And from the context, one might assume it's about time intervals or periods. If I'd had to guess, you might be after `hms::as_hms()`

Comment: Thank you Margusl for your reply. I tried
```
dput(head(df$ride_length))
```

And got this output: 

structure(list(ride_length = structure(c(358, 22, 501, 2022, 
232, 374), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

I tried:
```
as.numeric(lubridate::hms(x), "minutes")
```
but it threw parse warning: Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs and returned NA

Comment: It's better to update your original question with `dput`output.  I wouldn't mix `hms` class (a duration, which basically a time difference in seconds and based on standard `difftime` ) with `lubridate::hms()` , latter is for parsing strings, so that `hms` will be converted string first, and result is a more complex `period` object . Lubridate cheatsheet explains differences between durations, periods and intervals quite nicely -  https://rawgit.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/lubridate.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

```r
x <- c("09:10:00", "08:35:10", "22:45:30")
strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S")$min

Output
[1] 10 35 45
```

Comment: If question is about ride lenght in minutes, wouldn't you assume to get `22 * 60 + 45 + .5 = 1365.5` for `"22:45:30"` ?

Comment: Thank you @tanesya for your reply. The data as per this code

 ``` dput(head(df$ride_length)) ``` 

looks like: 

structure(list(ride_length = structure(c(358, 22, 501, 2022, 232, 374), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

So, I want to convert the whole hms value in the column to minutes: h*60 + m + s/60 and create a new column

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c("01:10:00", "02:35:10", "00:45:30")

as.numeric(lubridate::hms(x), "minutes")

# [1]  70.00 155.17  45.50
```

Comment: Thank you fror @Merijn for your time. I tried the code but it threw parse warning: Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs and returned NA

Comment: without showing us your data, including those where you get different results as expected it will be hard to help you. Appearently you have data that is not a string in hms format, all those will be converted to NA's

Answer (score 0):

As your actual data type seems to be `hms`, you can convert it to numeric to get seconds and divide by 60.

```r
# loading hms changes how hms columns are printed
library(hms)

# your dataset sample:
df <- structure(
  list(ride_length = structure(c(358, 22, 501, 2022, 232, 374),
    class = c("hms", "difftime"),
    units = "secs"
  )),
  row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"
)

df
#>   ride_length
#> 1    00:05:58
#> 2    00:00:22
#> 3    00:08:21
#> 4    00:33:42
#> 5    00:03:52
#> 6    00:06:14

# take a closer look at types:
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    6 obs. of  1 variable:
#>  $ ride_length: 'hms' num  00:05:58 00:00:22 00:08:21 00:33:42 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"

df$minutes <- as.numeric(df$ride_length) / 60
df
#>   ride_length    minutes
#> 1    00:05:58  5.9666667
#> 2    00:00:22  0.3666667
#> 3    00:08:21  8.3500000
#> 4    00:33:42 33.7000000
#> 5    00:03:52  3.8666667
#> 6    00:06:14  6.2333333
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>